# CREATE TABLE statements silently failing under executeBatch

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

Here is my part of a code. In this when I execute sql statements, the create table is not creating any tables in the database and there are no errors thrown. Why is this?

I'm using NetBeans with JDK SE 8 with MS-Access.

```
String sql1="Insert into Signup_Login (UserName,DOB,EmailId,Password) values ('"+name.getText()+"','"+dob.getText()+"','"+emailId.getText()+"','"+pass.getText()+"')";
String sql2="create table "+emailId.getText()+"Inbox(InMsgs varchar(1000), primary key(InMsgs))";
String sql3="create table "+emailId.getText()+"Outbox(OutMsgs varchar(1000), primary key(OutMsgs))";

Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/LENOVO/Documents/Email.accdb");
st=con.createStatement();
st.addBatch(sql1);
st.addBatch(sql2);
st.addBatch(sql3);
st.executeBatch();
```

Comment: set auto commit is `false`.

Comment: @Ticktick What is the error?

Comment: @MangeshGhotage There are no errors

Comment: You should use [`Statement.execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)) for DDL statements such as `CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UCanAccess 3.0.3.1 I was able to reproduce your issue with trying to run CREATE TABLE statements using `addBatch()`/`executeBatch()`. However, they seem to work okay if each one is run independently using `executeUpdate()`.

Also, because the VARCHAR columns are wider than 255 characters your CREATE TABLE statements will actually create tables with a "Memo" (a.k.a. "Long Text") field as their primary key. Creating such a table is not allowed in the Access UI and therefore should probably be considered "Not Recommended". Instead, use something like this to create a table with an AutoNumber primary key:

```java
String sql2="CREATE TABLE ["+emailId.getText()+"Inbox] (id COUNTER PRIMARY KEY, InMsgs MEMO)";
```

(... ignoring, for the moment, the fact that creating separate identical tables for each `emailId` is almost certainly a bad idea.)

Answer (score 0):

First, set auto commit is `false` using `setAutoCommit()` method

```
 con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Last, commit the connection using `commit()` method

```
 con.commit();
```

Code:

```
st=con.createStatement();
con.setAutoCommit(false);
st.addBatch(sql1);
.................
st.executeBatch();
con.commit();
```

Comment: There are no errors. But when I open the DB I cannot find those tables

Comment: This should work. Did you refresh the Database once the commit is done? The tables wont just get added in the UI. You will need to refresh.

Comment: Yea I did refresh it. @P.Jairaj

Answer (score 0):

Your tables aren't getting created because you set the primary key to `varchar(1000)`, where, maximum length for primary key is 767 bytes. so you must decrease the length of your key to be 767 and this depend on your table encoding. Setting varchar(767) doesn't mean 767 bytes, you can search for "the length of primary key in varchar", and if you don't need this 1000 length you can change to be `varchar(250)`.

if you receive email address in your text you should put your table name between (`) like this :

```
String sql2="create table `"+emailId.getText()+"Inbox` 
(InMsgs varchar(1000), primary key(InMsgs))";
```

Comment: I decreased it to 10. No use

Comment: what is the value of emailId.getText() ?

Comment: It is the string I enter in JTextField emailId.

Comment: Ok if you put complete email in your text field your should update your query to put your table name between( `)

Comment: Now it is throwing an error stating unexpected token emmaInbox